# long long array not returning expected value when calling index of 0 in c

Tags: c, arrays

Why does `printf("the value of str is \"%llu\"\n", str[0]);` not return the value of the first digit in array str?

When I try other index values (1, 2, 3) the expected value is returned?

Apprciate any help. Just started learning c.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    // a will hold the number
    unsigned long long int a=548763,i=0;
    // str will hold the result which is the array
    unsigned long long int str[20]= {};
    // first we need to see the length of the number a
    unsigned long long int b=a;
    while(b>=10)
    {
        b=b/10;
        i++;
    }
    // the length of the number a will be stored in variable i 
    // the while loop below will store the digit from the end of str to the 
    // the beginning 
    while(i>0)
    {
        str[i]=a%10;
        a=a/10;
        i--;
    }
    // only for test 
    printf("the value of str is \"%llu\"\n", str[0]); //[0]

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Step through your code mentally. Check edge cases. Does it work, say, for `a = 5`?

Comment: if a is a single digit, calling index 0 returns index 0. Which is the same behavior as any other number. But if call any other index it also returns 0

Comment: But does the array contain the correct value?

Comment: Note that an empty object initializer is non-conforming.  You should instead write `str[20]= {0}`.  That will initialize *all* elements, the first explicitly to 0, and the rest to their default initialization value, which happens to also be 0.

Comment: What result do you want if `a == 0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(i>0)
{
    str[i]=a%10;
    a=a/10;
    i--;
}
```

This loop isn't counting all the way to 0, it's counting down to 1. If `i` is never 0, `str[i]` is never set.

I suspect what happened is you wrote `while(i>=0)` and the compiler told you that won't work because `i` can never be negative because its unsigned. That's what happened to me. It's odd that the iterator is unsigned, perhaps because `i` is really the number of digits, but there's no real reason for that to be unsigned either. `i` should never get larger than 20, it could be a `short`.

The smallest fix is to store `i` as a signed integer and switch to `while(i>=0)`.

---

I'd go steps further and suggest:

- Storing the number of digits in `num_digits`.
- Make `i` just the iterator to avoid confusion.

`i` is commonly used as a loop iterator and it's a bad habit to use it for anything else or have its value persist into the next loop. If you have to do that, name it something else.

It also means that the number of digits is destroyed in the process of populating `str` leaving no way to print all of `str`. So store that separately in `num_digits` and copy it to `i` as needed.

- Use `for` loops.

For simple iterations, for loops make it very clear how it's initialized, how it's incremented, and what the end condition is. Your first loop is not good for a for loop, but your second is.

- Declare variables as they're needed.

This avoids forgetting the types, what they're initialized to, and what everything for. It also makes it easier to see what should be split out into a function.

- Change `str` to `digits`.

It's not a string.

- Change the type of `digits` to `short`.

`digits` is an array of individual digits, none will be larger than 9. Allocating 64 bits for each of them is overkill.

- `unsigned long long int` might overflow `str[20]`.

This is the other actual bug in the code. `unsigned long long int` is guaranteed to be *at least* 64 bits, but it could be more. If it is, that would overflow `str` which is fixed at 20. You'd have to either `malloc` the memory for `str` based on `num_digits`, or use `uint64_t` from [`stdint.h`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#stdint.h) to explicitly get an unsigned 64 bit integer.

---

Putting it all together...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{    
    // a will hold the number
    uint64_t a=548763;
```

We're using `uint64_t` instead of `malloc`ing `str`. YMMV, so long as `str` cannot be overflowed. I chose a fixed size to avoid introducing memory allocation, you might not have learned that yet. I kept it unsigned to not have to deal with the sign.

```
// first we need to see the length of the number a
int num_digits = 0;
uint64_t b = a;
while( b>=10 ) {
    b=b/10;
    num_digits++;
}
```

I left this as a `while` loop because it's not a simple iterator. The variables are declared as needed (this would make a nice little function). And it's storing the number of digits in `num_digits`, a simple integer.

```
short digits[20]= {0};    
for( int i = num_digits; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    digits[i]=a%10;
    a=a/10;
}
```

This has been reworked into a `for` loop to make it clear this is a simple iterator. `num_digits` has been copied to `i` so we can use `num_digits` later. And it goes down to 0. `digits` is now an array of `short`s, 1 byte integers; that's all it needs to store a list of digits from 0 to 9.

Note that an initializer of `{}` is non-standard. It should be `{0}` to initialize all the elements to 0.

```
for( int i = 0; i <= num_digits; i++ ) {
    printf("the value of str is \"%d\"\n", digits[i]);
}
```

The pay off is we still have `num_digits` around to iterate through `digits`.

---

This is probably an exercise. In production code you can accomplish basically the same thing with `sprintf`. This will also deal with negative numbers, no need for unsigned.

```
int64_t a=548763;

char str[22] = {0}; // 1 extra for the possible sign, 1 for the null byte.
sprintf(str, "%"PRId64, a);

for( int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++ ) {
    printf("the value of str is \"%c\"\n", str[i]);
}
```

Note that [the types from stdint.h have their own printf format specifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Printf_and_scanf_format_specifiers). `PRId64` is the PRIntf format for a 64 bit digit. It's a macro and has to be outside the quotes to expand into its own string. It takes advantage of adjacent C strings automatically concatenating at compile time.

```
printf("This " "is all " "one string!\n");
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! And I appreciate the tips on memory allocation conventions

Comment: @AndyC Thanks! I made a few small fixes and improvements, like what ilkkachu recommended. See the edits.

Comment: When the input is a series of numbers that begins with a zero (01234), it is ignoring the final zero. I think it has to do with the comment that @ilkkachu had but I'm not sure how to address this

Comment: I found out the issue is the custom function I am using to take user input to store into a. What is the best way to taking in user input and pass it to an uint64?

Comment: @AndyC `scanf("%"SCNd64)` to read the input string and convert it to a `uint64_t` in one step, but [`scanf` has serious problems](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html). `fgets` + `sscanf` is safer, read the whole input line with `fgets` into a string then `sscanf` to process it into `uint64_t` with error checking. But since the input is a string, there's no need to convert it to a number, then split it out into digits. You've already got the digits as characters of the string. So just `fgets` and use the resulting string.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to deal with the final (least significant) digit:

```
while(i>0)
{
    str[i]=a%10;
    a=a/10;
    i--;
}

str[i] = a;  // <---- last digit (here i == 0 and a < 10)
```

Comment: @FCo `while(i>=0)` would be an infinite loop for OP as `i` is unsigned.

Comment: @ilkkachu How would that look like?

Comment: @AndyC, I was thinking something like `do { str[i]=a%10; a=a/10; } while(i--)`   (I got it wrong the first time, it has to be a post-decrement)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code that I finally got to work as expected. 
I was never writing to index zero.

I changed `str[i]=a%10;` to `str[i-1]=a%10;`

Made a few other minor changes as well to get the loop to run properly since it was not doing the last loop. Thanks your help everyone.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    // a will hold the number
    unsigned long long int a=123456,i=0;
    // str will hold the result which is the array
    unsigned long long int str[20]= {0};
    // first we need to see the length of the number a
    long long int b=a;
    while(b>0)
    {
        b=b/10;
        i++;
    }
    // the length of the number a will be stored in variable i 
    // the while loop below will store the digit from the end of str to the 
    // the beginning 
    while(i>0)
    {
        str[i-1]=a%10;
        a=a/10;
        i--;
    }
    // only for test 
    printf("the value of str is \"%llu\"\n", str[1]); //[0]

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using a signed type for `b` and an unsigned type for `a` is not good practice.  Suggest both `unsigned long long`.  BTW, certainly `i` and `str[20]` can use a narrower type than `unsigned long long`.  Recommend `size_t` for indexing arrays.  Consider what happens when `a==0`.

Comment: Great advise. Thanks. What do you mean when recommend size_t for indexing arrays?

Comment: In this small code, `i` will never be large, maybe 0 to 20 or so, any integer type will work.  Yet in _general_ application where code indexes an array, what type `i` should be used?  Is `int` enough?  C _specifies_ `size_t` as wide enough to handle any valid index into an array.  It is some _unsigned_ type, so that needs consideration too.